# How do I access Cassandra from a Spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am new to using Spring Boot Applications. I would like to know how to connect cassandra database to the application.
I added this dependency in the pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And these lines to the application.yml file :

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: test-keyspace
      contact-points: localhost
      port: 9042
      schemaAction: CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
      request:
        timeout: 10s
      connection:
        connect-timeout: 10s
      locaDatacenter: datacenter1
```

However, when I run the application, I get such errors :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 

Error creating bean with name'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 


Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraSession' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 


Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraSessionBuilder' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 


Error creating bean with name 'cassandraDriverConfigLoader' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 


Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DriverConfigLoader]: Factory method 'cassandraDriverConfigLoader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CONNECTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Aaron's answer, there's a good chance that there's a version conflict in your deployment that's leading to the exceptions you posted.

It isn't necessary to specify the Cassandra Java driver as a dependency because Spring Boot will pull all the required dependencies + correct versions automatically for you.

Since you're new, I would recommend that you start with a working example instead of doing one on your own. The [Spring project](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.examples-repo) has a repository on GitHub with [Spring Data examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples) including one [specific for Cassandra](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/main/cassandra/example).

Additionally, DataStaxDevs recently ran an interactive workshop that shows you how to build a microservices app with Spring Data Cassandra and Spring Boot. Details of the workshop and the hands-on tutorials with full working code are available here -- https://github.com/DataStaxDevs/workshop-spring-data-cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the DataStax Java driver, try Spring Boot's dependency for Spring Data (which pulls in the DataStax driver itself):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks ! I added it and followed few instructions in this doc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.examples-repo